# Can't prevent Trigger recursion in Android Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I've been unable to prevent recursive triggers in my room database. I am trying to update a column is_updated in my RecipeEntity table to false whenever RecipeEntity has a value change through an Update trigger.

```
                // prevent recursion
                db.execSQL("PRAGMA recursive_triggers = OFF;");

                // create recipe trigger to update is_updated to false every time recipe is updated
                db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER is_updated_trigger BEFORE UPDATE" +
                        "       ON RecipeEntity" +
                        "       BEGIN" +
                        "           UPDATE RecipeEntity SET is_updated=false" +
                        "           WHERE recipeId = NEW.recipeId; " +
                        "       END; ");
```

This is called on database creation through onCreate using RoomDatabase.Callback();

The Query to update the RecipeEntity is just a normal Room @Update method.

**Error message:**

```
2021-05-25 15:03:07.422 4668-4821/com.habbybolan.groceryplanner E/SQLiteLog: (1) statement aborts at 64: [UPDATE OR ABORT `RecipeEntity` SET `recipeId` = ?,`onlineRecipeId` = ?,`name` = ?,`is_favorite` = ?,`description` = ?,`prep_time` = ?,`cook_time` = ?,`serving_size` = ?,`calories` = ?,
    
    
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-05-25 15:03:07.429 4668-4821/com.habbybolan.groceryplanner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
    Process: com.habbybolan.groceryplanner, PID: 4668
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: too many levels of trigger recursion (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:890)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:756)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:66)
        at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(FrameworkSQLiteStatement.java:46)
        at androidx.room.EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter.handle(EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter.java:70)
        at com.habbybolan.groceryplanner.database.dao.RecipeDao_Impl.updateRecipes(RecipeDao_Impl.java:531)
        at com.habbybolan.groceryplanner.database.DatabaseAccessImpl.lambda$updateRecipe$14$DatabaseAccessImpl(DatabaseAccessImpl.java:427)
        at com.habbybolan.groceryplanner.database.-$$Lambda$DatabaseAccessImpl$3OxencYWN3idP4iK5ncgMxJDuQc.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
2021-05-25 15:03:07.453 1017-1023/? E/statsd: Predicate 5980654721335871649 dropping data for dimension key (10)0x2010101->10361[I] (10)0x30000->*launch*[S] 
2021-05-25 15:03:07.488 1620-2075/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '99b1b43 Toast (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

For some reason, when I download the database from the device and run it inside the DB Browser software it works fine without causing any trigger recursion. It seems like something specifically with Room perhaps?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your issue is that you appear to be issuing the PRAGMA only in the `onCreate` callback.

This callback will only be called the once and I don't believe that the state persists. As such RECURSIVE_TRIGGERS is ON (left ON).

I'd suggest adding an **`onOpen`** callback to execute the PRAGMA.